# How can make input element displayed same as block element?

Tags: css, input

I want to make universal fluid element with solid one near him and place them in line:

```
// wrapper starts here
[=(XX%)=solid=] [---------------------(auto)-fluid-]
[=(XX%)=solid====================] [--(auto)-fluid-]
[-(auto)-fluid---------------------] [=(XX%)=solid=]
[-(auto)-fluid--] [=(XX%)=solid====================]
// wrapper ends here
```

But when I tried traditional variant with "float:" style attribute - failed on "input" element: http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/pMRD8/

Also tried hack provided in similar question: [What's keeping my input element from displaying like a block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424800/whats-keeping-my-input-element-from-displaying-like-a-block-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a little javascript and math:

```
var b = $("#mainWrap").css('padding').split('p')[0];
$("#fluidInput").width($("#mainWrap").width() - $("#btn1").width() - (b * 2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/pMRD8/4/

Comment: Nice answer, but can I avoid JavaScript to do that in CSS only?

Comment: I tried a few pure CSS approaches to fixing this, but the javascript is all I could come up with.  I like your commitment to keeping it CSS, but sometimes you have to journey to the darkside for some awesomeness :)